# CORS Settings for AWS Lambda via API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, blazor, webassembly

Am getting the following error:

`Access to fetch at 'https://...' from origin 'https://...' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

p.s. from blazor wasm web api call

Comment: What's the question ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure to set

Access-Control-Allow-Origin
*

Access-Control-Allow-Headers
*

Access-Control-Allow-Methods
*

p.s.

you may need to make the above more restrictive e.g. to your apps domain

also don't forget to clear your browsers cache

[image]

https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/main/develop/cors

Answer (score 1):

## [Enabling CORS support for Lambda or HTTP non-proxy integrations and AWS service integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)

> For a Lambda custom (non-proxy) integration, HTTP custom (non-proxy) integration, or AWS service integration, you can set up the required headers by using API Gateway method response and integration response settings. When you enable CORS by using the AWS Management Console, API Gateway creates an OPTIONS method and attempts to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to your existing method integration responses.

> **This doesn’t always work, and sometimes you need to manually modify the integration response to properly enable CORS. Usually this just means manually modifying the integration response to return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.**

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.example.com",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

Have you tried the following?